# E-Mail delivery configuration in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm fairly new to SSRS and after a long search on the internet I would ended up here trying to get a response. Is it possible to modify the body content of the e-mail with the 2008 R2 version of SSRS. I'm actually using this exactly tags on the RSreportserver.config.

```xml
<RSEmailDPConfiguration>
     <SMTPServer>mySMTPServer.Adventure-Works.com</SMTPServer>
     <SMTPServerPort></SMTPServerPort>
     <SMTPAccountName></SMTPAccountName>
     <SMTPConnectionTimeout></SMTPConnectionTimeout>
     <SMTPServerPickupDirectory></SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
     <SMTPUseSSL></SMTPUseSSL>
     <SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
     <SMTPAuthenticate></SMTPAuthenticate>
     <From>my-rs-email-account@Adventure-Works.com</From>
     <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
          <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
     </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
     <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats></PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
     <ExcludedRenderFormats>
          <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
          <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
     </ExcludedRenderFormats>
     <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias>
     <DefaultHostName></DefaultHostName>
     <PermittedHosts>
          <HostName>Adventure-Works.com</HostName>
          <HostName>hotmail.com</HostName>
     </PermittedHosts>
</RSEmailDPConfiguration
```

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? Standard.. Enterprise?? Are you trying to deliver automated reports via email?

Comment: Do you have SMTP configured for that server -->mySMTPServer.Adventure-Works

Comment: I'm using SSRS Enterprise, that config I took from Microsoft docs, but I put to you guys see what tags I'm using. The reports are been delivered just fine, but I can only see, at the web portal, a few fields: To, Subject and Priority. I would like to be able to edit the body of the e-mail for example.

Comment: Can you see a section called Comment on Step 4 when you create a data driven subscription? That is where you put whatever you want.. format your column in HTML and use that column in Comment (get the value from the database) and the resulting email body will look how you formatted the HTML.

Comment: Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155(v=sql.120).aspx